# How could I give a lower class function to a thread?

Tags: python, multithreading, function, class

```
import threading
class A:
    def func(self):
        print('asdf')

class B(A):
    def func(self):
        print('1234')

class C(A):
    def func(self):
        print('xyzw')
def f(inner_func):
    class_list = [A(),B(),C()]
    thread_list = []
    for i in class_list:
        x=threading.Thread(target=inner_func(i,),args=())
        thread_list.append(x)
        x.start()
    for i in thread_list:
        i.join()
f(A.func)
```

I thought this would print

```
asdf
1234
xyzw
```

but it just prints

```
asdf
asdf
asdf
```

How can I use the inherited classes' functions at once, without doing it manually?

Comment: How about `target=i.func`? Then the correct method will be supplied using runtime lookup resolution.

Comment: This could also be an [x-y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What's your actual use case/context of the problem? `x = threading.Thread(target=i.func)` is the full code described above (no need for an argument)

Comment: I asked the question wrong. I was making a function which does the thing that I've explained.

Comment: Changed the code ;-;

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do that by passing the name of your function as string, using:

> getattr(class, function_name)

```
import threading


class A:
    def func(self):
        print('asdf')


class B:
    def func(self):
        print('1234')


class C:
    def func(self):
        print('xyzw')


def f(inner_func):
    class_list = [A(), B(), C()]
    thread_list = []

    for i in class_list:
        x = threading.Thread(target=getattr(i, inner_func), args=())
        thread_list.append(x)
        x.start()
    for i in thread_list:
        i.join()


f('func')
```